# Keras fully connected followed by convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm not super amazing with keras yet, so please be gentle.

My input data is a matrix of size 60000 x 784.

I'm trying to add convolutional layers after my fully connected layers, something like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(784, input_dim=train_amplitudes.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(784, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(784, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(100, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28))
mode.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(train_targets.shape[1], activation='linear'))
```

Notice that 28 * 28 = 784.
I get the error "Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2" at the first convolution layer.

Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: You are not using is right I guess. Like input in the Conv2D layer is of 4 dim and you are giving a 2d array. And it will not automatically change the 2D array into 4D.

Comment: Before trying to attempt to fix the error, you should tell us what you want to do conceptually. Dense layers produce 2D vectors, and Conv2D layers work on input images (4D vectors), so of course there is a mismatch that is a lot more than just a programming problem. You need to tell us what the network should do.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro what I want is simple. I want to create a network that first has dense layers, followed by convolutional layers. That's it. I realize for the most part its the other way around, but I want to try this.

Comment: And how do you want to deal with the fact that dense layers do not produce images?

Comment: A grayscale image is a 2d matrix. The dense layers give me 1 x 784 dimensional output. this can be rearranged to 28 x 28 matrix, or in other words, a grayscale image.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of this specific network structure? Assuming that your original data was 28x28, you should leave the input with 28x28 and then apply conv2d. After that you can flatten the last output of the convolutional blocks to continue with the fully connected layers.

Comment: I don't want to do that. I specifically want to use the fully connected layers first

Answer (score 1):

In Keras, input shape argument is a 4D tensor with shape: (batch, channels, rows, cols) if data_format is "channels_first" or 4D tensor with shape: (batch, rows, cols, channels) if data_format is "channels_last". You're just passing rows and columns (what you think) but it also requires batch and channels. More information can be found [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/).

Comment: Even if I don't specify input shape (which according to the documentation I should only do when the layer is the first one), it still gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to fix it. This is the code that "works"

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(784, input_dim=train_amplitudes.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(784, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(784, activation='relu'))
mode.add(Reshape((28, 28, 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(100, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')
    mode.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(train_targets.shape[1], activation='linear'))
```

it works in the sense that no error is produced. Whether it makes sense or produces a good output, that's another matter, but this is good enough for me.